# Create Clickhouse DB and load lots of table with R

Tags: sql, r, dbi, clickhouse, dbplyr

I'm trying to create a Clickhouse DB and copy to a table the values from many files (all them equal column order).

But I'm not understanding how to deal with it.

I'm using [RClickhouse](https://github.com/IMSMWU/RClickhouse) which I don't know if has any difference compared to [clickhouse-r](https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/clickhouse-r).

```
library(RClickhouse)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)

eggnog_dir <- "/home/acpguedes/projects/sig_trans/data/eggnog/table/"
setwd(eggnog_dir)

myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = RClickhouse::clickhouse())

mytables <- list.files(".") # all tables are in the same folder 

mysqltb <- db_create_table(con = myconn, table = 'eggnog')


lapply(mytables, function(x) {
  read_tsv(file = x, 
           col_names = c( #in my case the tables has no header
             'sequence',
             'model',
             'start',
             'end',
             'evalue',
             'cov',
             'qstart',
             'qend',
             'iteration',
             'score',
             'talilen',
             'qlen',
             'estart',
             'eend',
             'program'
             )
           ) %>% dbWriteTable(conn=myconn, value = ., name = "domains", append=TRUE) 
  }
    ) -> dt
```

Don't matter the columns itself, I just would like an example of how to create a table and load to it the content of many files( tables like tsv ou CSV or any delim).

I also was trying with `dbpĺyr` using `copy_to()` instead `dbWriteTable`.

Also, afterload all tables, should I do a 'commit' statement to save permanently the database to posterior accession from R or other platforms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with your present approach? Can you write a table (and then read it back in) outside of the `lapply`? Is the problem with appending inside the `lapply`? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. thanks. I was able to write a table this way I did, but I wasn't able to read it outside R or after the restart a session.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can not read the table outside R or after a restart, it sounds like the issue is committing to the database.

Try something like the following after the `lapply`:

```r
my_commit_statement = "COMMIT"
dbExecute(myconn, my_commit_statement)
```

With the appropriate commit statement for your application.

The other (unlikely) possibility is that table creation, or writing, is temporary. Both `dbCreateTable` and `dbWriteTable` from the DBI package have an argument `temporary` with default value `FALSE` so this should not be the cause. But no harm in making this argument explicit, as one `temporary = TRUE` could keep your table from persisting. Also worth checking whether there is any difference between `db_create_table` that you are using and `dbCreateTable` from the DBI package.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm getting this error `Error in select(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 1: COMMIT. Expected one of: Query, SYSTEM, DETACH, DROP, ....` quiet long error. I'll try again an I'll update with the erros and other details

Comment: My first thought is that the commit statement is more complex than just `COMMIT`. I do not have the clickhouse background to advise you on this part of it - my experience is with dbplyr.